# Index satisfying tuples lexicographically for integers $0<a<b<c$ with rational $\sqrt{\frac{c-a}{c+b}},\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{c-b}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

Related to the question about [Triples of positive integers $a,b,c$ with rational $\sqrt{\frac{c-a}{c+b}},\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{c-b}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104820/triples-of-positive-integers-a-b-c-with-rational-sqrt-fracc-acb-sqrt), I'm interested in whether there is a way to get satisfying tuples $\left(a,b,c\right)$ in lexicographical order by an index.

The sequence is easily enumerable through iteration: 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&\left(a,b,c\right)\\
&: c \in [1, \cdots, \infty] \land b \in [1, \cdots, c-1] \land a \in [1, \cdots, b-1] \\
&\mid \, \left( \sqrt{\frac{c-a}{c+b}} \in \mathbb{Q} \right) \land \left( \sqrt{\frac{c+a}{c-b}} \in \mathbb{Q} \right)
\end{align}
\right\}
$$

but if you want the 1 billionth tuple, that is a lot of I-think-probably unnecessary work. Is there a way to directly calculate a tuple given an index into the lexicographically-sorted sequence?

---

**Edit:** Working on this some myself, I realized that it would probably be far easier to index the tuples by lexicographical order if we used $\left(c,b,a\right)$, since $c > b > a > 0$. This would be fine also.

---

**Edit2:** Just to reiterate (from the other thread) something I've found helpful, writing the equations as:
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
q \times r^2 &= (c-a)\\
q \times s^2 &= (c+b)\\
t \times u^2 &= (c+a)\\
t \times v^2 &= (c-b)
\end{align}\right.\\
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\{a, b, c\} &\in \mathbb{Z}\,\land\,(0<a<b<c)\\
\{q, t\} &\in \mathbb{Z}\\
\left\{\frac{r}{s}, \frac{u}{v}\right\} &\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{align}
$$
makes it explicit that the individual numerators and denominators need not be squares, only the quotients (so there can be a common non-square term that cancels between a numerator and denominator).

Comment: If i get something simple i will let you know. the one simple thing not mentioned at the earlier question is that this question is the same: $(c-a)(c+b)$ and $(c+a)(c-b)$ are integer squares. Most examples have $a=b,$ from Pythagorean triples. The original question required $b > a,$ so those did not come up

Comment: @WillJagy: I want tuples satisfying the other question, with $0 < a < b < c$

Comment: @WillJagy As the author of said question, I'm irked that I didn't notice that second characterization; for one, it'd have meant I didn't have to use so many \frac's!

Comment: @Semi Stop \frac'ing now